# how to change form field from dropdown list to radio button in django if the options in dropdown are being inherited from another model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

i am working on an application where i can select item from drop-down list and buy them. i have a form field which is a drop-down list(items are connected to other model via foreign key.i want to make those options appear as radio buttons instead of drop down list

**my models.py**

```
class Plans(models.Model):
    plan_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    speed = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.plan_name

def get_deadline():
    return dt.today() + timedelta(days=30)


class Orders(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, primary_key=True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    pack = models.ForeignKey(Plans, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(default=get_deadline())
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        name = str(self.user.username)
        return name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home-home')
```

**my forms.py**(i tried using the init method but my drop down list vanishes when i use it)

```
class BuyPlanForm(forms.ModelForm):
    error_css_class = 'error-field'
    required_css_class = 'required-field'

    class Meta():
        model = Orders
        fields = ['pack']
        

    #def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     #   super(BuyPlanForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      #  for field in self.fields.values():
       #     if isinstance(field.widget, forms.Select):
         #       field.widget = forms.RadioSelect()
```

**my views.py**

```
class UserBuyPlan(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'plans/plan.html'
    form_class = BuyPlanForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

please help.(sorry i tried my best to explain the problem i am having but my english isn't that great)[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i had to just add widget to my form field >>> `pack = forms.ModelChoiceField(Plans.objects.all(), widget=forms.RadioSelect())`

so my full form class looks like

```
class BuyPlanForm(forms.ModelForm):
    error_css_class = 'error-field'
    required_css_class = 'required-field'
    pack = forms.ModelChoiceField(Plans.objects.all(), widget=forms.RadioSelect())

    class Meta():
        model = Orders
        fields = ['pack']
```

Comment: Nah bro doesn’t work

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in your template:

```
{% for plan in order.plan_set.all %}
            <input type="radio" name="plan" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ plan.id }}">
            <label for="plan{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ plan.choice_text }}</label><br>
        {% endfor %}
```

For further information check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/ , I modified this code from there

Comment: I just had to add a widget to the form field.

Answer (score 0):

So try to do this in your form:

```py
class BuyPlanForm(forms.Form):
    
    park = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
          widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
          choices = Orders.pack,
          label = 'pack'
         )
```

Remove *forms.ModelForm* and replace it by *forms.Form*
and manage the adding in your view.

Tell me if it works. Thanks

Comment: I just had to add the widget to form field(worked fine with model form so I didn’t change it to forms.model). Thanks for the clue bro.